# Access listbox rowsource not updating via VBA

Tags: ms-access, listbox

Using: MS-Access 2013; Windows 8.1 Professional

I am trying to update the displayed values in a ListBox in Access by setting the RowSource property in VBA to an SQL statement. However its not working. The listbox does not show the results of the SQL.

Here is my VBA code:

```
Private Sub cmbStudent_Change()
  Dim s As Integer

  s = cmbStudent & ""

  ' cmbTerm is a ListBox

  cmbTerm.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"

  cmbTerm.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT Terms.TermID, Terms.TermName " & _
                      " FROM Terms " & _
                      " ORDER BY Terms.TermCode;"

   cmbTerm.Requery


End Sub
```

After cmbTerm.Requery, the listbox is still empty ie. its not drawing the values from the TERMS table.

Without using a RecordSet (ADODB.RecordSet) object is there any way to make this work?

[image]

Thank you in advance for any helpful inputs.

Comment: Does the query return any rows when run regularly?

Comment: Seems to me there is a much easier way to go about this using Cascading list boxes.  BlueClaw has some nice write-ups on the topic:
http://www.blueclaw-db.com/comboboxlist/access_dependent_dropdown_list.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue I had to fix it by putting this code at the end.

```
Me.Listbox.RowSourceType = "Value List"
Me.Listbox.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
```

Note I had to also put it in a sub above the one that declared the RowSource.

so the RowSource is in a sub that is called by the main RowSource